# Transfer Joomla data from PHPMyAdmin SQL Dump

Tags: database, sql, backups

My friend's web page was created with Joomla (c. 2013), and she wants to transfer her site to a new host. Her current host sent her a SQL Dump generated by PHPMyAdmin, which contains what I assume is the Joomla database tables, schemas, and data (i.e. it contains CREATE TABLE and INSERT VALUES statements, but I've never worked with Joomla, so I'm not positive these are from the Joomla back-end). How difficult is it to re-create her site from this data? I can work with databases (so I could rebuild the database from the SQL Dump) but have no web development experience. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the SQL Dump to recreate the database using phpMyAdmin or similar.

You will also need the Joomla files to be able to recreate the Joomla website.

Once the files and the database have been recreated, you will likely need to edit the `configuration.php` file in the root folder of the website and update the database credentials to the new values:

- $host
- $user
- $password
- $db
- $dbprefix

and also update the paths to the tmp and logs folders:

- $tmp_path
- $log_path

If there are any initial issues with the moved website, try backing up the `.htaccess` file (if there is one) in the root folder of the website to `.htacess.old` or similar and copy the default `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess` to see if this helps.

Comment: it's also a good idea to go thru the SQL with a text editor (such as notepad++) if the hosting user account name has changed, and turning error reporting to 'maximum' in the joomla `global config > server` settings helps find those pesky plugins causing whitescreen

Answer (score 2):

Is the old website still accessible? If yes, then I think the safest and easiest way to transfer joomla website is to use [Akeeba Backup](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/akeeba-backup) component. You just need to install this component and then create a backup.Once the backup is created then you just need to extract the backup in the new host and run the installation instruction.